# Outputting encrypted PK8 private key from Java BouncyCastle

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, private-key, pkcs#8

I am trying to generate an encrypted private key and CSR using Java in Matlab. Matlab adds some minor complexity, but this is mostly a Java problem. I start with a private key:

```
java.security.Security.addProvider(org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
keyGen = java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance('RSA', 'BC');
keyGen.initialize(2048,  java.security.SecureRandom());
keypair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
privateKey = keypair.getPrivate();
```

If I encrypt the key and output it as PEM:

```
m=org.bouncycastle.openssl.PKCS8Generator.PBE_SHA1_3DES;
encryptorBuilder = org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8EncryptorBuilder(m);
encryptorBuilder.setRandom(java.security.SecureRandom());
encryptorBuilder.setPasssword(password);
oe = encryptorBuilder.build();
gen = org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPKCS8Generator(privateKey,oe);
privKeyObj = gen.generate();
fos = java.io.FileWriter('private.pem');
pem = org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter(fos);
pem.writeObject(privKeyObj);
pem.flush();
fos.close();
```

I get a perfectly good key. The problem is that I want to use the key with jdbc, so I need a DER formatted pk8 key. I cannot figure out how to get this out of BouncyCastle. A kludge workaround that succeeds:

```
textWriter = java.io.StringWriter();
pem = org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter(textWriter);
pem.writeObject(privateKey);
pem.flush();
thekey = char(textWriter.toString());
cmd = ['echo "' thekey '"|openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -out private.pk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -passout pass:' password];
system(cmd);
```

Now, obviously this exposes both the unencrypted private key and the password. I've tried all manner of things to coerce privKeyObj to DER, but they typically leave me with:

```
$openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -outform PEM -in private.pk8 -out private.pem
Error decrypting key
140735211835472:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1201:
140735211835472:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:765:
140735211835472:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:697:Field=version, Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
```

The intent of this code is to generate a CSR on the end user's machine which I then sign, and which is encrypted with MAC address of the machine (and a salt), so that the program will only run on the authorized machine, and only authorized machines will be able to access my PostgreSql database.

Suggestions?

Comment: Note that I completely missed this post since it was missing the Java and cryptography tags. Always use top level well visited tags and indicate your language. That's more important than using the more specific ones: they basically serve to make your question being noticed by others.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. In my original code, I had used BcPKCS12PBEOutputEncryptorBuilder. Wrong! The correct call is to JcePKCSPBEOutputEncryptorBuilder. The correct code (in MATLAB, but converting to Java is simple) is:

```
    java.security.Security.addProvider(org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    keyGen = java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance('RSA', 'BC');
    keyGen.initialize(2048,  java.security.SecureRandom());
    keypair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    privateKey = keypair.getPrivate();
    builder=org.bouncycastle.pkcs.jcajce.JcaPKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfoBuilder(privateKey);

    m=org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pbeWithSHAAnd3_KeyTripleDES_CBC;
    encryptorBuilder = org.bouncycastle.pkcs.jcajce.JcePKCSPBEOutputEncryptorBuilder(m);
    password = 'test';
    outputBuilder = encryptorBuilder.build(password);
    privKeyObj = builder.build(outputBuilder);
    fos = java.io.FileOutputStream('testkey.pk8');
    fos.write(privKeyObj.getEncoded());
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

This generates a DER formatted PCS#8 file.

```
    openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -outform PEM -in testkey.pk8 -out testkey.pem
```

Now returns the PEM private key. To read the key:

```
    myPath = java.nio.file.Paths.get(pwd,'testkey.pk8');
    encodedKey = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(myPath);
    privKeyObj =org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(encodedKey);
    cp=org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter();
    cp.setProvider('BC');

    decryptorBuilder = org.bouncycastle.pkcs.jcajce.JcePKCSPBEInputDecryptorProviderBuilder();
    inputBuilder = decryptorBuilder.build(password);
    info = privKeyObj.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(inputBuilder);
    decodedKey=cp.getPrivateKey(info);
```

Note that in MATLAB, you don't need to declare the type of the returned object, and you don't need to put "new" in front of a constructor.